# How to remove the functionality of changelist filter appearing in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

**How do I remove this filter and its functionality completely out of the admin page?**

[image]

I'm trying to display only the users whose staff status is true and I think the query isn't working because of the filter's 'By staff status' set to 'All' on page load. Anyway how to remove it totally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `list_filter = ()` to the model definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've found another way clearer to do that. If you see the source code of the auth class (User Class) the admin looks like this:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form_template = 'admin/auth/user/add_form.html'
    change_user_password_template = None
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    change_password_form = AdminPasswordChangeForm
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    ordering = ('username',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return self.add_fieldsets
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Use special form during user creation
        """
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults['form'] = self.add_form
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **defaults)

    def get_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r'^(.+)/password/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.user_change_password), name='auth_user_password_change'),
        ] + super(UserAdmin, self).get_urls()

    def lookup_allowed(self, lookup, value):
        # See #20078: we don't want to allow any lookups involving passwords.
        if lookup.startswith('password'):
            return False
        return super(UserAdmin, self).lookup_allowed(lookup, value)

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    @csrf_protect_m
    @transaction.atomic
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # It's an error for a user to have add permission but NOT change
        # permission for users. If we allowed such users to add users, they
        # could create superusers, which would mean they would essentially have
        # the permission to change users. To avoid the problem entirely, we
        # disallow users from adding users if they don't have change
        # permission.
        if not self.has_change_permission(request):
            if self.has_add_permission(request) and settings.DEBUG:
                # Raise Http404 in debug mode so that the user gets a helpful
                # error message.
                raise Http404(
                    'Your user does not have the "Change user" permission. In '
                    'order to add users, Django requires that your user '
                    'account have both the "Add user" and "Change user" '
                    'permissions set.')
            raise PermissionDenied
        if extra_context is None:
            extra_context = {}
        username_field = self.model._meta.get_field(self.model.USERNAME_FIELD)
        defaults = {
            'auto_populated_fields': (),
            'username_help_text': username_field.help_text,
        }
        extra_context.update(defaults)
        return super(UserAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url,
                                               extra_context)

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def user_change_password(self, request, id, form_url=''):
        if not self.has_change_permission(request):
            raise PermissionDenied
        user = self.get_object(request, unquote(id))
        if user is None:
            raise Http404(_('%(name)s object with primary key %(key)r does not exist.') % {
                'name': force_text(self.model._meta.verbose_name),
                'key': escape(id),
            })
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.change_password_form(user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                change_message = self.construct_change_message(request, form, None)
                self.log_change(request, user, change_message)
                msg = ugettext('Password changed successfully.')
                messages.success(request, msg)
                update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(
                    reverse(
                        '%s:auth_%s_change' % (
                            self.admin_site.name,
                            user._meta.model_name,
                        ),
                        args=(user.pk,),
                    )
                )
        else:
            form = self.change_password_form(user)

        fieldsets = [(None, {'fields': list(form.base_fields)})]
        adminForm = admin.helpers.AdminForm(form, fieldsets, {})

        context = {
            'title': _('Change password: %s') % escape(user.get_username()),
            'adminForm': adminForm,
            'form_url': form_url,
            'form': form,
            'is_popup': (IS_POPUP_VAR in request.POST or
                         IS_POPUP_VAR in request.GET),
            'add': True,
            'change': False,
            'has_delete_permission': False,
            'has_change_permission': True,
            'has_absolute_url': False,
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'original': user,
            'save_as': False,
            'show_save': True,
        }
        context.update(admin.site.each_context(request))

        request.current_app = self.admin_site.name

        return TemplateResponse(request,
            self.change_user_password_template or
            'admin/auth/user/change_password.html',
            context)

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        """
        Determines the HttpResponse for the add_view stage. It mostly defers to
        its superclass implementation but is customized because the User model
        has a slightly different workflow.
        """
        # We should allow further modification of the user just added i.e. the
        # 'Save' button should behave like the 'Save and continue editing'
        # button except in two scenarios:
        # * The user has pressed the 'Save and add another' button
        # * We are adding a user in a popup
        if '_addanother' not in request.POST and IS_POPUP_VAR not in request.POST:
            request.POST['_continue'] = 1
        return super(UserAdmin, self).response_add(request, obj,
                                                   post_url_continue)
```

In the admin of **any application** you can unregister the user class, define your custom UserAdmin and then, register it again:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
...
admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    list_filter = ()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Putting `list_filter=()` you are overriding the default filter telling django that you don't want any filter, so it won't appear. And you can override any configuration from the default one in this Admin Class.

**EDIT**:
You have to add the function queryset, to filter the objects you want to show. For your purpose, you have to do the following:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    list_filter = ()

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(is_staff=True)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: +1 as that is correct, I have already tried it, it removes the filter from the page. But it does not remove the default 'All' on page load. **(ie) the functionality is still there, but hidden.** So even though I have written a query to display only _is_staff = True_ for the models, it ignores the query and displays all.

Comment: Yeah, I already had the queryset with a Q object but it ignores that and displays all nonetheless..

Comment: I'm with 1.7.7 and the code that I've put works perfect for me. Have you tried you `get_queryset(self, request)` instead of `queryset(self, request)`?

Comment: There is another way but I don't know how to work this, could you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447570/how-to-achieve-this-manipulation-in-the-django-admin-page)