# How to achieve this manipulation in the Django-admin page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When the user clicks on 'Users - Pending' in the picture below:

[image]

he should be **redirected to the page with the filter by staff status set to 'No' and not 'All' which is the default.** The url of that, which appears on clicking 'No' is this http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/pending/?is_staff__exact=0:

[image]

What do I need to change where to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_queryset(self, request):

q = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
if request.user.is_superuser:
    return q
return q.filter(is_staff = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this def in your 'UserPendingAdmin' class:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    """Limit list display to instances that belong to the request's user."""
    qs = super(UserPendingAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    # this if you want superuser to see all
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(user__staff_status = False)
```

Comment: yes, i had already tried queryset, it didnt work here for some reason